# Closing custom flag yellow migration warning box, then clicking Flag Question button triggers "wait 5 seconds" error

Tags: bug, flags, migration, custom-flags, moderator-intervention

It may be a little deceiving in this gif, but the occurrences per loop are:

1. Click <kbd>Flag question</kbd>
2. Click the mustard popup to close it
3. Click <kbd>Flag question</kbd> to action the flag
4. Receive red popup

The first button click should not count as an attempt to flag because it is impeded by the mustard popup.

This looped animated gif shows that the red "You may only flag a post every 5 seconds" warning is displayed after clicking <kbd>Flag question</kbd> then closing the mustard-colored migration popup then clicking the <kbd>Flag question</kbd> a second time.

> [image]

<sub>(using spoiler formatting so that you can reload the page and hide the distracting animated gif.)</sub>

Comment: This is only a bug if it's waiting 5 seconds from the time you *dismiss* the mustard popup. If it's 5 seconds from the time you first click "Flag question", then that's good. You need to spend *at least* 5 seconds reading the mustard pop-up and considering whether you really want to request migration of the question.

Comment: I can accept that rationale.